# How to use Instagram graphql?

Tags: instagram, graphql

I'm using the following query 
`https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_id=17851374694183129&id={acountId}&first=1000&after={cursor}`
to get an user followers. The information I need is the `followed_by_count` index that's only available per user on `https://www.instagram.com/{username}?__a=1`

Is there a `query_id` that includes the `followed_by_count` in the result?

Comment: Wish to know more about this too

Answer (score 7):

This `query_id` code `https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_id=17851374694183129&id=<user_id>&first=1000&after=<end_cursor>` is designed to return ONLY media data it does NOT include user profile data.

The simplest solution is to use what IG uses on initial page requests:

`https://www.instagram.com/<ig_username>/?__a=1`

Here is my RubyOnRails setup:

`profile = JSON.parse(open("https://www.instagram.com/<ig_username>/?__a=1").read)`

... now grab your variables:

```rb
profile.['graphql']['user']['profile_pic_url']
 
profile.['graphql']['user']['biography']

profile.['graphql']['user']['external_url']

profile.['graphql']['user']['edge_followed_by']['count']

profile.['graphql']['user']['edge_follow']['count']

profile.['graphql']['user']['id']

profile.['graphql']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['count']

profile.['graphql']['user']['profile_pic_url']

profile.['graphql']['user']['profile_pic_url_hd']
```

And your `followed_by_count` is now `['graphql']['user']['edge_followed_by']['count']`

Comment: @chen-doron - hopefully the above answer will work for you too.

Comment: Does this still work? Or has it been culled along with those listed at https://www.instagram.com/developer/?

Comment: @Ollie unfortunately this too has been deprecated. Currently there is no easy method for accessing public data via a public json request.

Comment: What is the limit for using https://www.instagram.com/<ig_username>/?__a=1

per user per hour ?

Comment: @Mark new here... how do you pick a correct value for the query_id? you have 17851374694183129, how did you set that value? I tried other values and it does not work. Only using 17851374694183129 works. could you help me understand that? Thanks

Comment: @zumzum the query_id was supplied within the original post. I was just clarifying the query called returns ONLY media data and NOT the profile data. BTW the solution I supplied too  get profile date NO LONGER is valid.

Comment: From where we get <end_cursor> value ?