# Instagram error while trying to get followed by count

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api, notice

My site has been receiving instagram subscribes with this script for about last 5 month:

```
<li class="instagram">
            <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo Yii::$app->config->getConstSite("LINK_PAGE_INSTAGRAM"); ?>">
                <i class="icon-instagram"></i>
                <?php if (!empty($followers_in)): ?>
                    <span class="quan"><?= number_format($followers_in["user"]["followed_by"]["count"]) ?></span>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <span>Followers</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Yesterday I received notice

> Undefined index: user

. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

With the recent changes of Instagram API, you can use the following code to get the followers count:

```
<?= number_format($followers_in['graphql']['user']['edge_followed_by']['count']); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, Gustavo, it works now. Maybe, you can advise some web sources, where I can read about such recent changes on APIs?

Comment: I'm glad to help you! Actually, I'm also missing information on this, but I suppose the return syntax of the requests looks much like the graphql API. There are two links that help you with this: [Instagram ?__a=1 url doesn't allow max_id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49270809/7153717) and [How to use Instagram graphql?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49275814/7153717)